# convert single value array within a nested object to a single value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have a nested object where I'd like to convert an array of a single value `group`, into a single value:

```
real_data = [
  [
    {x: 1, group: [1]},
    {x: 9, group: [2]},
    {x: 3, group: [3]}
  ],
  [
    {x: 2, group: [1]},
    {x: 4, group: [2]},
    {x: 10, group: [3]}
  ],
  [
    {x: 1, group: [1]},
    {x: 5, group: [2]},
    {x: 12, group: [3]}
  ],
  [],
    [
    {x: 1, group: [1]},
    {x: 5, group: [2]},
    {x: 12, group: [3]}
  ]
]
```

I've tried using map here but have been struggling due to the nested nature of the array. I also tried and struggled with some nested for loops. The desired output is:

```
desired_output = [
  [
    {x: 1, group: 1},
    {x: 9, group: 2},
    {x: 3, group: 3}
  ],
  [
    {x: 2, group: 1},
    {x: 4, group: 2},
    {x: 10, group: 3}
  ],
  [
    {x: 1, group: 1},
    {x: 5, group: 2},
    {x: 12, group: 3}
  ],
  [],
    [
    {x: 1, group: 1},
    {x: 5, group: 2},
    {x: 12, group: 3}
  ]
]
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: as mentioned in the original post I tried using a `map` and a nested for loop but because they were not successful I didnt see any value in posting code that doesnt work. Ill keep working at it and will add some pseudo code if I get any farther!

Comment: You're supposed to show (research) effort to solve the problem on your own. A _"please give me a working solution"_ is not enough. We happily help with broken code to fix it, but SO is not a free code writing service -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple.

1. Loop complete outer array
2. Loop inner array
3. Set value of `group` in inner array

```
real_data = [
  [
    {x: 1, group: [1]},
    {x: 9, group: [2]},
    {x: 3, group: [3]}
  ],
  [
    {x: 2, group: [1]},
    {x: 4, group: [2]},
    {x: 10, group: [3]}
  ],
  [
    {x: 1, group: [1]},
    {x: 5, group: [2]},
    {x: 12, group: [3]}
  ],
  [],
    [
    {x: 1, group: [1]},
    {x: 5, group: [2]},
    {x: 12, group: [3]}
  ]
];

var desiredOutput = real_data.map( elements => {
    let newElements = elements.map(element => {
        element.group = element.group[0];
        return element;
    });
    return newElements;
})
```

Comment: Note that this will modify the original input which may or may not be what the OP initially intended. (Just FYI)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result without modifying the original input -

```js
const input =
  [[{x:1,group:[1]},{x:9,group:[2]},{x:3,group:[3]}],[{x:2,group:[1]},{x:4,group:[2]},{x:10,group:[3]}],[{x:1,group:[1]},{x:5,group:[2]},{x:12,group:[3]}],[],[{x:1,group:[1]},{x:5,group:[2]},{x:12,group:[3]}]]

const output =
  input.map(x => x.map(({ group: [group], ...y }) => ({ ...y, group })))
  
console.log(output)
```

```js
[
  [
    {x:1,group:1},
    {x:9,group:2},
    {x:3,group:3}
  ],
  [
    {x:2,group:1},
    {x:4,group:2},
    {x:10,group:3}
  ],
  [
    {x:1,group:1},
    {x:5,group:2},
    {x:12,group:3}
  ],
  [],
  [
    {x:1,group:1},
    {x:5,group:2},
    {x:12,group:3}
  ]
]
```

Comment: What do you think of the comma operator in this case? To avoid extra spreading e.g. `input.map(x => x.map(({ group: [g], ...y }) => (y.group = g, y)))`

Comment: this is a toy problem, so there's no right/wrong solution. the only "problem" i see with it is `y.group = g` is imperative and mutates `y`. `y` is "fresh" in this case and so the original input is not mutated, but at first glance it looks like a mutation and that's usually enough for me to find a way to avoid it. destructuring is also a bit unreliable if the input data is dirty or misshapen. a more hygienic approach might be `input.map(x => x.map(y => Object.assign({}, y, {group: y?.group?.[0]})))`, which allows `group` to be absent and/or a non-array.

Answer (score -1):

based on the desired output you can use the following

```
real_data.map(o=>{
    return o.map(p=>{
        return {...p, group:parseInt(p.group.toString(),10)}
    })
})
```

Comment: Why `.toString()` and `parseInt()`? o.O

Comment: @MayaGans Please use the [version from Ahmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69270720/402037). Converting the array to a string and then parse it as number is overly complicated and error prone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).